# How to dockerize

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I am playing with my small server, trying to dockerize the services running on it. To simplify, let's say I have to main things : a Wordpress and another service.

There are plenty of images for Wordpress on Docker hub, but all of them seem to launch the web server (Apache2) *and* PHP-FPM. I don't see how it is compatible with the docker philosophy stating that there is "one process per container". **Am I wrong ?**

So I use docker-compose to launch three containers: `web_db` (MariaDB), `web_server` (nginx) and `web_fpm` (PHP-FPM). With `web_server` is monted the volume `./www`, which contains the data. Thus, after having placed the Wordpress files in `./www/wordpress`, I can access it and install it ilke a classic Wordpress installation by going on `http://my-ip/wordpress`. **Is it the correct way to do it ?**

Now that my Wordpress is up and running, I'd like to add another service. But then, I don't really know what is the best practice. Should I simply create `./www/other-service`, and so use the same containers? It seems to me that having only one container for a process is better (for example, why have two containers executing PHP-FPM?), but maybe I should avoid that to isolate my services. More precisely, I think that it could be good (i.e. necessary) to create a second container with a second database. **Can/should I have one container for nginx, one for PGHP-FPM and two containers for the two databases? Or should I re-create an entire stack for the other service, with a third nginx in front to do the proxy and managing the HTTPS and certificates?**

Answer (score 1):

> Can/should I have one container for Nginx, one for PHP-FPM and two containers for the two databases? Or should I re-create an entire stack for the other service, with a third nginx in front to do the proxy and managing the HTTPS and certificates?

Hi,

What I did for my wordpress network (10+ wordpress on OVH Cloud) is creating a stack for each Wordpress with:

- 1 Wordpress container with Apache/PHP and mounted volume for my wp-content folder
- 1 Mysql container with mounted volume for /var/lib/mysql
- 1 Nginx proxy container
- 1 Let's encrypt container

This configuration is when I got one wordpress on one host. If I need to launch several Wordpress in the same host I launch a stack with Nginx proxy + Let's encrypt and then a Wordpress/Mysql stack per wordpress.

I never expose directly the Wordpress containers ports and all my domains/vhosts are configured by the Nginx proxy container and auto-configured to use SSL from Let's encrypt.

Here is one example of my **Rancher stack** for one **Wordpress** on one host:

```
    db:
      environment:
        MYSQL_PASS: MYSQL_PASS
      labels:
        io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
        io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: server=TARGET
      tty: true
      image: tutum/mysql:5.5
      volumes:
      - /home/docker/wordpress/mysql/lib:/var/lib/mysql:rw
      stdin_open: true
    letsencrypt:
      labels:
        io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
        io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: server=TARGET
      tty: true
      image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:latest
      volumes:
      - /home/docker/nginx-proxy/ssl:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      volumes_from:
      - proxy
      stdin_open: true
    proxy:
      ports:
      - 443:443/tcp
      - 80:80/tcp
      labels:
        io.rancher.sidekicks: letsencrypt
        io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
        io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: server=TARGET
      tty: true
      image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:latest
      volumes:
      - /etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /usr/share/nginx/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - /home/docker/nginx-proxy/ssl:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /home/docker/nginx-proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d:rw
      stdin_open: true
    wordpress:
      environment:
        DB_NAME: DB_NAME
        DB_PASS: DB_PASS
        DB_USER: DB_USER
        LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL
        LETSENCRYPT_HOST: LETSENCRYPT_HOST
        VIRTUAL_HOST: www.nicolashug.com, nicolashug.com
        VIRTUAL_PORT: '80'
        WP_ADMIN_EMAIL: WP_ADMIN_EMAIL
        WP_ADMIN_PASSWORD: WP_ADMIN_PASSWORD
        WP_ADMIN_USER: WP_ADMIN_USER
        WP_PROTO: https
        WP_URL: www.nicolashug.com
      log_driver: ''
      labels:
        io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
        io.rancher.scheduler.affinity:host_label: server=TARGET
      tty: true
      log_opt: {}
      image: krustyhack/wordpress:latest
      links:
      - 'db:'
      volumes:
      - /home/docker/wordpress/wordpress/wp-content:/app/wp-content:rw
      stdin_open: true
```

When the stack start the first time my Wordpress container will auto install Wordpress with wp-cli, configure it with my admin login, password, email, ... and then install my plugins and my templates. This allow me to launch a lot of Wordpress without having to install them by the url.

When I need several Wordpress on one host I use the same stack but without the Nginx proxy and Let's encrypt part which I put in a separate Rancher stack.

Even if I prefer to separate ALL apps/services with Docker in this case I found it simplest to put Apache/PHP/Wordpress in one container.

The next thing I need to do is to separate Mysql from the stack to put all databases on one server but it's not the discussion here :p

For your question what I would do is one stack per Wordpress with container Apache/PHP, container Mysql and another stack with Nginx proxy and Let's encrypt for all your Wordpress on the server.

I hope my english wasn't too bad. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I agree with you regarding one process per container, however, I am not sure about it any more either. For example this article has been published on the Docker website: `https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/`

To answer your second question, yes you are right,you just need the IP of your physical host / container to navigate to your WordPress installation. Also the link above shows exactly how to do so.

Well depends what you are trying to achieve, as there isn't a good way or a bad way, is all about personal preferences and the hardware you are running on. If you have lots of disk space and RAM available, you can have a single DB for each WordPress installation, otherwise, you could have a web_db which holds all your WordPress DBs.

More here:

```
https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-the-official-docker-wordpress-image/
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-and-phpmyadmin-with-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-14-04
```